# Detecting if stream_socket is valid

Tags: php, sockets, stream

I have a PHP server-like script that runs indefinitely. It connects to APNS (*Apple Push Notification Service*) with a stream_socket_client object in PHP.

The problem is that while this works most of the time, I cannot figure out how to validate if the connection to APNS is available when I want to send a push notification. The script receives incoming connections and copies the content to APNS.

When it doesn't work, the script reconnects (the return value of stream_copy_to_stream is 0 on 0 bytes written, which triggers reconnect) and then the next incoming token will succeed, but it logs the following and of course does not deliver the message:

```
PHP Warning:  stream_copy_to_stream(): SSL: An established connection was 
aborted by the software in your host machine.
```

Is there any way to detect the above and thus reconnect to APNS **before** trying to write to the socket.

And doing this before trying to copy to APNS:

```
if (!$socketObject) { 
    // reconnect
}
```

Does not work, as the object still exists (var_dump will print a description). So how can I check if the connection is still open?

Writing anything to the socket that is not a valid token and payload will cause APNS to disconnect.

The code that performs the writing looks like this:

```
  function writeToAPNS($client) {
        return stream_copy_to_stream ( $client, $this->connectionAPNS );
    }
```

Where `$client` is returned from `stream_socket_accept ( $this->socket, -1 )` and `$this->socket` is a variable containing the local socket object listening for incoming connections. -1 means there is no timeout when waiting for an incoming connection. When it works this function returns the number of bytes written. When it fails it returns 0.

`$this->connectionAPNS` is the object returned from `stream_socket_client` when connecting to APNS. This is what I want to check for validity before I perform the `stream_copy_to_stream` function.

So basically I want to detect if `$this->connectionAPNS` is *valid*.

I tried dumping the metadata for the connection object, but it doesn't say anything about the validity, only if it's timed out, protocol type etc.

Comment: You missed to show something reproducible.

Comment: I will add some more code then. Hold on.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see this note in the official [stream_socket_client](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php) documentation?

> UDP sockets will sometimes appear to have opened without an error, even if the remote host is unreachable. **The error will only become apparent when you read or write data to/from the socket**. The reason for this is because UDP is a "connectionless" protocol, which means that the operating system does not try to establish a link for the socket until it actually needs to send or receive data.

Please try this methiod [stream_get_meta_data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php) on your connection to try to detect a difference. I can't test it right now, but it might help you. Especially the **timed_out** property.

Another option to at least mute the error messages, since you are handling them, is to set an appropriate **errno** on the stream_socket_client.

Comment: I did, but I'm not opening a UDP connection, so this does not apply. APNS does not operate on the UDP protocol.

Comment: @nickdnk If none if it is useful to you I will remove my answer.

Comment: The UDP part is not. The rest is. I tried using stream_get_meta_data, but it doesn't seem to tell me if the connection is valid, only the type, if timed out etc.

Comment: The problem is that your $stream can not become null after a while. You can only perform checks this way right after the stream creation. So the only way I see right now to avoid this situation is for you to create a new client every time. (don't forget to close the old one)

Comment: Yea that's what I was thinking of too. I guess the error logged is logged after PHP has determined that the socket is not valid (by trying to write to it).

Comment: I assume so. Php is not designed to run indefinitely. There are some limitations that must be considered.

Comment: I suppose I could store the incoming connection in a variable instead of copying it directly, then if the writing fails, reconnect and write the incoming connection again after reconnecting.

Comment: Or you could create a new connection > write > close. Repeat.

Comment: It's too slow, but yes, I will ultimately have to do that if my current plan doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as explained by M.K., this is how UDP works. And by the way, your code works. Your problem is the warning, which is fairly easy to get rid of by adding an @ to your write function.
Your code would then look like :

```
 function writeToAPNS($client) {
    return @stream_copy_to_stream ( $client, $this->connectionAPNS );
}
```

Comment: But it's a TCP socket!

Comment: I am going to rebuild this solution on Java though, and make it multithreaded so it can handle many requests at once. But so far this PHP solution has been working well. I solved it by reconnecting after 1 hour of inactivity.